# How can I get an image as my Woocommerce shop page header background?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

My Woocommerce category pages have the option to change thumbnail and it goes on the header area of the page (under the main menu), but there isn't such option for Woocommerce shop page. Maybe because it is an archive page?

My Woocommerce shop page header has a white background, so there is a white space between main menu and products. Page title also is displayed in this area. I know how to change this background color, but I would like to upload an image.

So - How can I get an image as my Woocommerce shop page header background?

Thank you!

Comment: If this isn't supported by your theme, you could just add it using CSS yourself. Could you share your code / the page you want the image on?

Comment: Hello, Sam! How can I do that? This is the page - http://watchempire.co.uk/shop/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to fix this quite easily with CSS.

```
.opacity-light.bg-dark-gray {
  opacity: 1;
  background-image:url('IMAGE_URL_HERE');
}
```

To be certain it doesn't override your other pages, you could be more specific with the selector so that it only targets the div on that type of page, so:

```
.post-type-archive-product .opacity-light.bg-dark-gray { .. }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, this is working! Thanks! I did not add this ".post-type-archive-product" line because this background image fits my tag pages also. If I do add that line, then my tag pages would not have this background.

Comment: @rudolfs Great, glad it's working. If you want it to apply to your tag pages too you could perhaps find a unique selector for that page too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my site using [SKT builder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/skt-builder/). To change the grey header of the shop page.
Click "**Customize** (live preview) >> **Post & Page** >> **Post Header Setting**".

[Insert image you want to display by clicking "Select Image"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRY10.png)

Comment: That is going to work great for browser windows of the right size but is not mobile responsive

Comment: Updated the solution. It's now responsive and can be edited through the live preview using SKT builder.